# Prolog: Deleting atom in nested lists

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to delete an item in a list. My code works but it doesn't delete the symbol in a nested list.

In the second to last rule I'm trying to check if the next element is a list. What am I doing wrong?

```
del(Symbol, [], []) :-
   !.
del(Symbol, [Symbol|Tail], Result) :-
   !,
   del(Symbol, Tail, Result).
del(Symbol, [[List]|Tail], Result) :-
   !,
   del(Symbol, List, Result2),
   append([List], Result2, Result).
del(Symbol, [Other|Tail], Result) :-
   !,
   del(Symbol, Tail, Result2),
   append([Other], Result2, Result).
```

Comment: Please show concrete queries you expect to succeed (together with the answers you want to get).

Comment: What is the concrete form of the "nested" lists? Something regular like matrices (commonly represented in Prolog as lists of lists like `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]`) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

once you have a working del/3 on a flat list, you can extend it to handle nested lists, checking the type of the first element: if it's a list, recurse and keep the outcome.

To check the type, you can use [is_list](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=is_list/1)/1